# List all items in autocomplete when click the tetxbox

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Here My code when I type the text box ,auto complete items listed in textbox using below code

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [<?php echo $data_list;?>]; 
$( "#ethnicity" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
})
});


<input   type="text" size="20" id="ethnicity" name="ethnicity"  >
```

how to list all the list when focus or click the text box

Comment: call this function on `onclick` event of the textbox.

Comment: Refer this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: @sridhar : In that script I am not getting list when i focus or click the textbox.List only get when i type in textbox